# How do I fix my CSS grid layout so that my aside shows up in preview, like my other sections? Also how do I get pictures in correctly?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

This is my third ever web development project, and I am running into a wall with CSS grids. I cannot get my aside section to show up when I preview my page. There is just a blank section. Every other section works just fine. Although, I did try putting in a photo to the figure section and it blew the whole thing out OR took up one box of the grid rather than the whole grid area I wanted it to take up. I haven't tried any other sections of the grid yet, but I am genuinely worried the issue is going to apply to all of them. I think I am missing something obvious here but I've been at it for 12 hours.

### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Catherine's Canine Classes</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <p id="header">Hello</p>
    <p id="nav">nav</p>
    <p id="figure">Figure</p>
    <p id="figcaption">figcap</p>
    <p id="nav1">nav1</p>
    <p id="form">form</p
    <p id="aside">aside</p>
    <p id="footer">footer</p>
    <p id="section1">section1</p>
    <p id="section2">section2</p>
    <p id="section3">section3</p>
    <p id="section4">section4</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

### CSS

```
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image: url('Background.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
* {
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.4;
  font-size: 16pt;
  margin: 5px;
}
a[href] {
  cursor:pointer;
}
#header {
  grid-area: header;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
}
#figure {
  grid-area: figure;
  justify-content: stretch;
  align-content: stretch;
}
#nav {
  grid-area: nav;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
}
#aside {
  grid-area: aside;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
}
#nav1 {
  grid-area: nav1;
  justify-content: stretch;
  align-content: stretch;
}
#form {
  grid-area: form;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
}
#section1 {
  grid-area: section1;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: start;
}
#section2 {
  grid-area: section2;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: start;
}
#section3 {
  grid-area: section3;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: start;
}
#section4 {
  grid-area: section4;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: start;
}
#footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: start;
}
#figcaption {
  grid-area: figcaption;
  justify-content: start;
  align-content: center;
}
@media only screen and (max-width : 1600px) and (min-width : 1281px) {
  .container {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 24% repeat(4, 19%);
    grid-template-rows: 25% 30% 30% 15% 20% 60% 20%;
    grid-template-areas:
      "header figure figure figure figure"
      "nav figure figure figure figure"
      "nav figure figure figure figure"
      "aside nav1 nav1 nav1 nav1"
      "aside form form form form"
      "aside section1 section2 section3 section4"
      "footer footer footer footer footer";
    justify-items: stretch;
    align-items: stretch;
    background-color: #ffffff77;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width : 1280px) and (min-width : 701px) {
  .container {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 25%);
    grid-template-rows: 25% 40% 15% 20% 60%;
    grid-template-areas:
      "header nav nav nav"
      "figure figure figure figure"
      "nav1 nav1 nav1 nav1"
      "form form form form"
      "section1 section2 section3 section4";
    justify-items: stretch;
    align-items: stretch;
    background-color: #ffffff77;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width : 700px) and (min-width : 0px) {
  .container {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 100%;
    grid-template-rows: 20pt 30% 40% 15% 30% repeat(4, 50%); 
    grid-template-areas: 
      "nav"
      "header"
      "figure"
      "figcaption"
      "form"
      "section1"
      "section2"
      "section3"
      "section4";
    justify-items: stretch;
    align-items: stretch;
    background-color: #ffffff77;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to happen on viewports wider than 1600 and where do you want aside to be in viewports 1200 or less?

Comment: from first look you are missing a closed tag   <p id="form">form</p

Comment: for the image to fit the cell #figure img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

Comment: The assignment has us stopping at 1600, and aside is a section that does not exist in the other viewport sizes. We have to follow a given template from the visual alone. 

The missing closed tag fixed it thank-you so much! I added the bit for the figure (just added img and then put the width and height below), and it is still only in one grid container (not all) and doesn't show up on the smaller viewports.